# Input fields not visible on Community

Tags: visualforce, community

I have created a VF page for add employee with 12 fields and added to community. These fields are visible when i login as salesforce user. But when i login as community user 4 input fields do not show up only the label is visible.
This 4 fields which are not visible are lookup fields where the controlling field being account. Is there any settings i need to enable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be issue with Field Level Security. Provide appropriate FLS at community User's profile. 
To set FLS follow

1. Setup->Manage Users->Profiles
2. Open Community User's Profile/Profiles.
3. Go To Field Level Security Section .
4. Click view against the object to which your fields belong.
5. click Edit to modify FLS as per your requirements.

Comment: Hi Mukesh,    Thanks for the help. I did change the fls and now i am able to see some fields and some fields are still readonly even after giving the edit permission on fls.

Comment: Its resolved with profiles i also added fls on permission set that resolved the issue. Thanks for the holp Mukesh.